# r - pass string stored in variable in dplyr function

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I want to supply a string stored in a variable as a new column name while performed a dplyr group_by function. How can I retrieve the value stored inside the variable, and not the name of the variable, as a string?

```
# store label name
l <- var_label(df$Q8b_1)

# group variable and supply label to new column based on mutate
# DOES NOT WORK
df %>%
  group_by( as_factor(Q8b_1) ) %>%
  summarise(n=n()) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(pct = n/sum(n) * 100) %>% 
  rename(l = pct) %>% # use label inside l, not literal "l"

# result
 as_factor(Q8b_1)   n           l
                1 252  38.4732824
                2 261  39.8473282
                3 112  17.0992366
                4  25   3.8167939
                5   5   0.7633588
            Total 655 100.0000000
```

Comment: Your first line of code is a bit confusing.  `var_label` is it from a separate package?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It is from the `labelled` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do the `rename_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Q8b_1 = as_factor(Q8b_1) ) %>%
  summarise(n=n()) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(pct = n/sum(n) * 100) %>% 
  rename_at(vars(pct), ~ l)
```

Or use

```
  rename(!! l := pct)
```

Comment: The second option worked, but the first threw an error: Unknown column `Research` ("Research" is the value stored in l)

Comment: @erics I think the issue is because of not quoting the 'pct'.  I was thinking that it is also from a stored object

Comment: @erics Ok, i think in `rename_at`, it should be reverse `rename_at(vars(pct), ~ l)`